# How is CSS font size PT units affected by pixel density

Tags: html, css, font-size

I keep reading that a "pt" unit for font size equates to 1/72 inches.  How exactly does this work in web pages?  I mean, do browsers scale it according to pixel density?

For example, if I use 72pt font size, it should be 1 inch (with rounding).  For high pixel density screens, will it just use more pixels so that it's still 1 inch?

The reason why I'm asking is because I made a test web page with 72pt font.  When I send it to my phone (Chrome on Android), it's smaller than when I view it on my pc (Chrome/IE on Windows 7).

This is what I'm testing with:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>

 <body>
  <span style = "font-size:72pt">This is 72pt font...</span>
  <span style = "font-size:144pt">This is 144pt font...</span>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: pt is for print, not web pages. I can't find my link to the W3C article about this.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html